# PlantUml Graphviz generates 2 duplicate diagrams

Tags: doxygen, graphviz, plantuml

I have this markdown code that is going to be generated into an html file using plantuml and graphviz.

```
 @image html Module23Static.png TC3
 @startuml{Module23Static.png}
   caption Module Dependencies and Interfaces of Module 23
   skinparam componentStyle uml2
     package "SW_Component"{
       [Module 1\n--\n provided interfaces:\n func1\n data1\n--\n required interfaces:\n Module2\n Module3] as M1
       [Module 2\n--\n provided interfaces:\n func2\n--\n required interfaces:\n interface_3\n Module4] as M2
       [Module 4\n--\n provided interfaces:\n func7\n func8] as M4
       M1 ..> M2 : use
       M2 ..> M4 : use
     }
 @enduml
```

This block of code will generate the same diagram twice, one after the other. I want it to create the diagram once only.

If I remove the line "@image html Module23Static.png TC3", it gives me a "Dot Executable:  File does not exist Cannot find Graphviz..." error. I already have Graphviz 2.50 and Doxygen 1.8.14 installed, and I have also set the GRAPHVIZ_DOT variable.

I am running on Windows, and using a batch file to generate the doxygen with plantuml and graphviz installed.

What am I missing here? Anyone encountered the same issue before?

Comment: What am I missing here?: The tag doxygen! Which version of doxygen are you using?

Comment: I am using doxygen 1.8.11.

Comment: Doxygen 1.8.11 is quite old, December 30 2015. Please upgrade to the current version (1.9.3)

Comment: Doxygen 1.8.14 is also quite old (December 25, 2017) So the advise is still: upgrade to the current version (1.9.3)

Answer (score 0):

Doxygen will, based on the `@startuml ... @enduml` create an image with the name `Module23Static.png` and add it to the output. Beforehand you also use `@image html Module23Static.png TC3` and this also adds the same image, hence you get twice the image.

So you can remove the `image html Module23Static.png TC3`

Comment: If I remove the line "@image html Module23Static.png TC3", it gives me an image of "Dot Executable: File does not exist Cannot find Graphviz..." error.

Comment: Is dot installed and available in your path? You don't have to set the environment variable `GRAPHVIZ_DOT` for plantuml when  the dot executable is available in your path.